# Some basic questions about Smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I had a few questions regarding Smart contract:

1) Are smart contracts legal like the traditional contract worldwide?
 
2) I read many pros and cons of smart contract where pros weigh higher, hence why aren't they been implemented fully?

I read a lot of links but I couldn't find the right answer to my questions.

Can someone please provide me answers to the above question with valid links to refer to?

Comment: Asking for a link is off-topic here

Comment: Legal questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, as are general 'pros and cons' questions (which are opinion-based).

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, smart contracts are a technical construct that was conceived by Nick Szabo in 2001 and published in the [FirstMonday journal](https://firstmonday.org/ojs/index.php/fm/article/view/548/469). I recommend you read his paper to get a better idea.

Smart contracts have however only recently been implemented in distributed systems. The advent of blockchain offered a suitable framework that allowed for decentralized execution of virtualized program code. One of the first frameworks was the Ethereum blockchain framework, which executes Solidity smart contracts in the Ethereum Virtual Machine. By now, there are many other technical methods of executing smart contracts (examples: Hyperledger Fabric uses chaincode (language-agnostic), run in Docker containers; EOS uses Web Assembly). These smart contracts are used in many [decentralized applications](http://stateofthedapps.com/) these days and are mostly used to run services in a decentralized fashion, without a trusted third party.

They are not equivalent to legal contracts so far in any country (as far as I know). There are [efforts](https://www.coindesk.com/connecticut-lawmakers-seek-to-legalize-blockchain-smart-contracts) to make smart contracts legally binding in some US states. There are also several tech companies working on integrating technical smart contracts with legal contracts. See [here](https://www.coindesk.com/blockchain-smarts-contracts-real-world-law) for an article discussing the differences between real-world law and smart contracts and what it takes for the latter to impact the former.